# How to make a Menu inside Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

### Overview

I'm developing a card game. Sometimes though the user may want to start over and create a new game, that's why I thought having a button in a corner that pops up a 'floating' menu where the user has the option to start a new game and quit the current one.

---

I know how to start over a new game, but I don't know how to make a button appear in every fragment (I have a FragmentManager) capable of making pop up a Menu, possibly a floating one so the user can still see what's behind.

I took a look at this [API Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#xml) for Menus but I'm not sure how to use this for my purpose, what do you suggest?

---

### Example

Here's an example of the Menu I'd like to achieve:
[image: Example of Menu requested]

Comment: Have you tried an `AlertDialog`?

Comment: That's more like a `Dialog`.

Comment: Alright, Dialog. Hoever, how about how to make this button be visible in every Fragment? Should I 'simply' add this button in every fragment's XML layout?

Comment: Have you looked a Floating Action Button? Attach to you activity hosting the  various fragments and it will be common across them all.

Comment: You can use PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(getActivity().... with a custom View.

Then popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new popupListener());

class popupListener implements OnMenuItemClickListener {

  @Override
  public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

Comment: I'd like the button to be in a corner like the one in the pic @ScottishUser

Comment: Looking at your example, you could drop a button at desired layout location, trigger an activity dialog with you custom layout (like above), this activity then handles your button logic?

Comment: PS I suspect your example image is using an activity dialog.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a menu, it's called `Dialog` in Android. You need to google how to create custom `Dialog` in Android. You will see lots of tutorials that do this.

Comment: How to make that button available in every fragment though?

Comment: Since you will write your custom dialog as a separate class, you can call it from any Activity you want.

Comment: Mmmm, I mean, how do I make the button which calls the Dialog, visible in every fragment?

Comment: If that was the answer, I didn't get it Ugurcan

Comment: Search for the keywords: Activity, actionbar, menu

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to declare your custom dialog class:

```
public class CustomDialog extends Dialog {
   public CustomDialog(final Context context) {
       super(context);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_custom_layout);
    (...)
   }
}
```

you can start another activities using context passed through constructor etc.